# Deleting rows with column that references the same table takes bizzare amount of time

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, constraints

Sorry for a pretty specific question.

I have a table (see bottom), and when I try to delete a lot of records from it, my PostgreSQL 8.2.5 spends 98% of the time doing the parent-child constraint.
I'm trying to figure out what index should I add to make it go fast.
I have to say that all columns on this table have either 0 or null as the `parent_block_id`: it's rudimentary.

I've tried adding different indexes: just (parent_block_id); WHERE parent_block_id = 0; WHERE parent_block_id IS NULL; WHERE parent_block_id != 0. Neither of those resulted in a serious perfomance benefit.

```
varshavka=> explain analyze delete from infoblocks where template_id = 112;
                                                 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on infoblocks  (cost=0.00..1234.29 rows=9 width=6) (actual time=13.271..40.888 rows=40000 loops=1)
   Filter: (template_id = 112)
 Trigger for constraint $1: time=4051.219 calls=40000
 Trigger for constraint $2: time=1616.194 calls=40000
 Trigger for constraint cs_ibrs: time=2810.144 calls=40000
 Trigger for constraint cs_ibct: time=4026.305 calls=40000
 Trigger for constraint cs_ibbs: time=3517.640 calls=40000
 Trigger for constraint cs_ibreq: time=774344.010 calls=40000
 Total runtime: 790760.168 ms
(9 rows)



varshavka=> \d infoblocks
                                      Table "public.infoblocks"
     Column      |            Type             |                      Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     | not null default nextval(('IB_SEQ'::text)::regclass)
 parent_block_id | integer                     |
 nm_id           | integer                     | default 0
 template_id     | integer                     | not null
 author_id       | integer                     |
 birthdate       | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "infoblocks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "zeroparent" btree (parent_block_id) WHERE parent_block_id <> 0
Foreign-key constraints:
    "$2" FOREIGN KEY (nm_id) REFERENCES newsmakers(nm_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "$5" FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "cs_ibreq" FOREIGN KEY (parent_block_id) REFERENCES infoblocks(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: the first (zeroth!) thing you should do when noticing ugly query times is make sure that you have `VACUUM ANALYZE`d recently.

If you just need a one-off deletion, then see [araqnid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911246/postgresql-deleting-rows-with-column-that-references-the-same-table-takes-bizzar/911324#911324).  But if you need something that will continue to work in the future when some rows have a nonzero, non-null `parent_block_id` field, read on.

I'm guessing that PostgreSQL doesn't combine the deletions caused by `ON DELETE CASCADE` into a single query -- the fact that the `EXPLAIN` output shows these as triggers suggests that each child row deletion will in fact be performed separately.  Presumably each row will be found using indexed lookup on `parent_block_id`, but that's still going to be much slower than a single sweep through the table.

So, you could probably get a big speedup by changing the `ON DELETE CASCADE` to `ON DELETE RESTRICT`, and manually compiling a list of all deletions that need to be performed in a temporary table, then deleting them all at once.  **This approach will be very fast if the maximum depth of your hierarchy is small.**  Here's some pseudocode:

```
# Insert the top-level rows as "seed" rows.
INSERT INTO rows_to_delete
    SELECT id, 0 FROM infoblocks WHERE template_id = 112

# Gather all rows that are children of any row at depth curLevel,
# advancing curLevel until no more children are found.
curLevel = 0
while (nRowsReturnedFromLastInsert > 0) {
    INSERT INTO rows_to_delete
        SELECT ib.id, rtd.level + 1
        FROM infoblocks ib
        JOIN rows_to_delete rtd ON (ib.parent_block_id = rtd.id)
        WHERE rtd.level = curLevel

    curLevel = curLevel + 1
}

DELETE FROM infoblocks
    JOIN rows_to_delete rtd ON (infoblocks.id = rtd.id)
```

(I'm not sure, but you may in fact need to use `ON DELETE NO ACTION` instead of `ON DELETE RESTRICT` for the final `DELETE` to succeed -- it's not clear to me whether a single `DELETE` statement is allowed to delete a parent and all its descendents when `ON DELETE RESTRICT` is in effect.  If that's unacceptable for some reason, you could always loop through multiple `DELETE` statements, first deleting the bottommost level, then the next-bottommost and so on.)

Comment: Thanks for a hint, I'll try it tomorrow. As for VACUUM ANALYZE, I did that, it helped ~tenfold in absolute numbers but didn't change the underlying O(N^2) a bit.

Comment: You were absolutely right, ON DELETE RESTRICT magically destroyed teh problem!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have tried adding an index to `template_id`?

Comment: this is the real problem, its doing a sequential scan, and only one of them.

Comment: put a hash index on it if they're ident fields not intended to be sorted or used for anything other than lookup, btree if order is meaningful.

Comment: The problem is not the seq scan, the problem is that Trigger for constraint cs_ibreq: time=**774344.010** calls=40000

Comment: yes, but the constraint appears to be checked for every item in the sequential scan, not the subset of results that match the criteria.

Comment: also, newsmakers(nm_id) , users(user_id) and infoblocks(id)  will all want indexes otherwise the dependant tables will *also* incur sequential scans, and that'll be death slow.

Comment: I agree with Kent.
Could it be a BEFORE DELETE FOR EACH ROW? Docs says _for each row_ are processed for all affected rows (just one). More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Maybe the ON DELETE CASCADE has some impact... What is the code of the constraint cs_ibreq?

Comment: @Kent: *Why* would the constraint be checked for *every* item in the sequential scan? I can't believe that the PostgreSQL developers would really allow something that wasteful...

Answer (score 2):

If you can handle blocking everyone else out for a while, maybe drop the constraint `cs_ibreq`, do the delete, and then re-add the constraint?

Possibly because there is only one non-null value for `parent_block_id`, it's not using the index when checking the constraint? Although that seems a bit odd.

Comment: +1, but note that this won't work in the general case when some records have a nonzero, non-null parent_block_id field.

Comment: With such index, the result is more or less the same.